# I am trying to fit the image inside the div in react mui i made it's maxWidth & maxHeight properties to 100% and object fit cover and it's not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

> <Box sx={{
> background: 'blue', width: '700px', height: '700px', borderRadius: 5
>
> ```
>     }}>
>       <img src={house} alt="" sx={{
>         maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'
>       }}></img>
>     </Box>
>
>   </Box
> ```

Comment: Can you provide a resulting html/css?

Comment: As resulting in the html ( a div as a parent elemnt and an image as a child ) but there is only styles applied on the div and no styles for the image appearing in chrome developers tool

Comment: Does old plain `style="max-width: 100%; ... "` work for you?

Comment: Edit your correctly with `indentation`.